# iPhone / iOS - [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResources not able to see Javascript files

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, nsbundle, nsdocumentdirectory

I have added a javascript file to my app resource bundle which I need to move to the documents directory but when I initiate its path for copying it returns null.

Code:

```
NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jsFile" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *copyPath = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/jsFile.js"];  //path is the documents dir
NSLog(@"%@", jsPath); //Output of this is (null)

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:jsPath]) //returns false
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:jsPath toPath:copyPath error:nil];
```

Has anyone very encountered this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if your js-file is compiled, rather than being copied to the bundle. You'll need to look under "build phases" for your current target...

Comment: Yes I just found this solution in another question on Stack as well but I didn't notice it before because it was not ticked as the correct answer. Regardless, you are correct.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution!